# Man in a cave with a silver ring

Tags: story-identification, movie

We want to identify a movie we watched years ago, but we don't know the name — but here is what we can remember:

- A man in a cave with a silver ring around his neck;
- Said man has no body;
- When people found him, they began yelling, and he experienced serious pain.

We really want to know what this movie is, any ideas?

Comment: How could he have a silver ring around his neck if he has no body?

Comment: How many years ago was "years ago"?

Comment: @Valorum One might guess, it was an apparition with a silver ring around its neck, and also that the ring trapped the spirit in the cave.

Comment: @Spencer - I heard that he was sad about the prom. Because he had no body to go with. Ba-doom-tish!

Comment: Sounds like parts of several episodes of Dr. Who where they have disembodied heads.  "Heads have rights too".